# Get and use current folder name inside a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

On a server I have a root folder with several 100 other folders named %Computername% inside it (created by their respective computers using mkdir).

These %Computername% folders contain a bat file which must be unique to that folder (the %Computername%). The bat file will consist of any number of commands for remote administration, for example:

schtasks /run /s %Computername% /tn "Task"

Is it possible to make the bat file automatically grab the folder's name (the %Computername%) without having to manually change it, and use that in its specified commands as the above example.

Comment: Idea 1: xcopy "Change me to %Computername% as I am run"   or       Idea 2: xcopy "Change me to %Computername% when this bat file is created in this %Computername% folder"

Comment: I found better answers for me in https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CD` command along `FOR` to retrieve current path, output only the folder name and ping it.

**Test.bat:**

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%i IN ('cd') DO set ADDRESS=%%~nxi
ping %ADDRESS%
```

**Result:**

```
C:\Users\Aybe\127.0.0.1>test.bat

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\Aybe\127.0.0.1>
```

**Another example:**

```
C:\Users\Aybe\yahoo.com>test

Pinging yahoo.com [98.139.183.24] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 98.139.183.24: bytes=32 time=116ms TTL=48
Reply from 98.139.183.24: bytes=32 time=120ms TTL=48
Reply from 98.139.183.24: bytes=32 time=116ms TTL=48
Reply from 98.139.183.24: bytes=32 time=119ms TTL=48

Ping statistics for 98.139.183.24:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 116ms, Maximum = 120ms, Average = 117ms

C:\Users\Aybe\yahoo.com>
```

Comment: I dont think this will work for my application. I need the folder's name to replace/append %computername% in the bat file. For example: ping %Computername%, where %Computername% would be retrived from the folder's name

Comment: thanks alot for the clarification. It is working as expected. Is there a way to make it reference a folder within a folder, as in your example: where "C:\Users\Aybe\yahoo.com>" would be "C:\Users\Aybe\AnotherFolder\AndAnotherFolder\yahoo.com>", yet still ping yahoo.com. Will mark your answer correct as it is what I am looking for.

Comment: Scratch that, I realised it wasn't pinging because of a space in the foldername (New Folder). You answer works 100%. Thanks again